# In topologies is $\in$ the same as $\subset$?

Tags: general-topology

In topologies is $\in$ the same as $\subset$?

Particularly, was thinking of the subspace topology:

Given a $(X, \tau)$ and $S \subset X$. A subspace top. is

$$\tau_S=\{ S \cap U : U \in \tau \}$$

Now since $\tau$ is some family of subsets of $X$, then it's a set.

Clearly $U$ is also a set, since it's intersected with a set.

But what then motivates saying $U \in \tau$, rather than $U \subset \tau$?

Comment: No. $\tau$ is a set whose elements are, in turn, sets.

Comment: $U \in \tau$ means that $U$ is an open subset of $X$. So $S$ and $U$ are both subsets of $X$.

Answer (score 3):

No. The topology $\tau$ is a set whose elements are sets contained in $X$. For an example, consider the topology

$$\tau := \{\emptyset, \{0\}, \{1\}, X\}$$

on the space $X = \{0, 1\}$. Then $\{0\} \in \tau$, but $\{0\} \nsubseteq \tau$ because $0 \notin \tau$.

Comment: Yeah I see, "minor" but important difference.

Comment: But I guess it could also depend on the topology? Would it be possible to have a topology that has sets of sets (of sets ...)? In which case $\subset$ "could" in theory work?

Comment: You could have some elements for which $a \in \tau$ and $a \subset \tau$ both hold, but it cannot hold for all of them.